# java how to manage callback correctly

Tags: java, process, callback

I will try to be clear with my question.
I had a callback function in a class like that, udes to retrieve card information from a reader.

```
public void CallbackFunction(CardContent PresentedCard) {
        
        }
```

So normally, i could write my code into this callback function for example if i want to print the content of the card data => this part doesn't take a long time.

But imagine if i want to do a big process that request a long time, like i need to transfert the information in different server so far away => this could take a long time

So what i understand is that during this time if a new card is presented on the reader, i supposed that the callback will be not wake up during this long time, and i will must wait the end of the previous process (send all the data to all the servers) for detecting a new card again.

So my question is what's the best practice to manage this case with a callback function ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a thread to handle a long-running callback function. The callback function may handle new card events without being blocked.

Here's how to utilise Java's Thread class:

```
public void CallbackFunction(CardContent PresentedCard) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        // long-running process here
        sendDataToServer(PresentedCard);
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

The callback function may handle new card events while transmitting data to the server in this example.

Executor, Future, and CompletableFuture provide extra thread management choices.

The callback function might add card information to a message queue, and a separate thread would process the queue and transmit the data to the server. If necessary, this method may retain event order.

It's also vital to handle problems and exceptions throughout the long-running process and appropriately end or interrupt the thread if the programme is closed or the process takes too long.

Comment: What is `Task.Run()`? Remember that this question is about Java.